# what does 'condition' mean here in swift tutorial ----function?

Tags: swift

I know that in the first line, we can use ***lessThanTen(number: Int)*** to replace ***(int)***, and ***contidion*** means a label, but in the third line: * why dont we use ***if condition : (item)*** to replace ***if condition(item)***, since ***condition*** is a label.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Condition is the method that you're receiving on that method, if you look at that method signature:

```
condition: (int) -> Bool
```

which means that you're receiving a condition that can be called using an argument of Int type and will return a bool. Anywhere, inside:

```
hasAnyMatches
```

you'll be able to use

```
condition(anyInt)
```

---

Now if you look at the method caller:

```
hasAnyMatches(list: numbers, condition: lessThanTen)
```

so, you're saying that the 'condition' on 'hasAnyMatches' will be 'lessThanTen'. Which means that in your

```
if condition(item)
```

What really is happening is:

```
if lessThanTen(item)
```

I hope it made it clearer!

Comment: Why can we use "lessThanTen" to replace "condition"?  Since "lessThanTen" is a function title, but "condition" is label.

Comment: And since in the first line, "condition" stands for a label. do you know what "condition" in the third line stands for? If it stands for a label, why don't we use ":" after it. Or we don't use it because it is just a rule that we can ignore it? On the other hand, we know that: in the first line: (int) stands for a function, which is "lessThanTen" here, and (item) in the third line also stands for a function, why don't we change "condition(item)" into "(item)"?

Answer (score 4):

`condition` is a `Bool`-returning closure supplied to `hasAnyMatches` that needs to be *called* to yield a boolean value. The closure takes a single argument of type `Int`, which is the same type as the elements of `list`. Hence, we *call* the supplied `(Int) -> Bool` closure on each item, and in case `condition` applied to an item returns `true`, we cut the traversal over the `list` items short and return `true` from the function.

Using functional programming tecniques, we could make use of a `reduce` operation on `list` to compress the implementation of `hasAnyMatches`:

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: (Int) -> Bool) -> Bool {
    return list.reduce(false) { $0 || condition($1) }
}
```

Or, even better (allowing exit `return` as in the original loop), as described by @Hamish in the comments belows (thanks!), using `contains`

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: (Int) -> Bool) -> Bool {
    return list.contains(where: condition)
}
```

Example usage:

```
func lessThanTen(number: Int) -> Bool {
    return number < 10
}

var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
print(hasAnyMatches(list: numbers, condition: lessThanTen)) // true
```

Comment: Note that using `contains(where:)` would be better than `reduce` in this case, as it'll return early upon finding `true` (you could also just say `return list.contains(where: condition)`). Although we've now really reached the point where the `hasAnyMatches` function is completely redundant from a practical perspective ;)

Comment: @Hamish true, totally forgot about `contains`, better here and also better reflects the original `for` loop. As a side note, I believe that `reduce` will also allow short-circuiting, I recall testing this out (however using a few unnessary boolean calculations), but naturally `contains` is better fit for the purpose, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: No problem :) Just curious, how were you thinking of getting `reduce` to short-circuit? The only way I can think of achieving that is to define a custom `Error` type and throw it from within the function passed to `reduce` (and then on the caller side catch it and return)

Comment: @Hamish Thinking it over, it might've been mistake on my part back when I analyzed this, but I drew the naive conclusion (simply based on benchmarking execution times of reducing vs simple early exit `for` loops) that compiler magic would reduce (no pun intended) a simple reduce operation as above to something similar to "`condition1() || condition2() || ... || conditionN()`" which would allow short-circuiting at runtime, for the first `true` returning `conditionX()`. But again, when I think it over it seems less likely, but it would be interesting to get back and do a better analysis of this.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't quite realise you were talking about compiler optimisation. I don't *believe* that the compiler can short-circuit it simply due to the fact that the length of the array isn't known until runtime (although I suppose there is potential for aggressive optimisation if the compiler knows it's working with an array literal, but I have no idea whether it actually does that or not). I agree it certainly would be interesting to see exactly what the compiler's able to do in this situation – I'll try and do some research of my own if I get time :)

Comment: @Hamish good point about the runtime array length. Let me know if you find out anything interesting :)