# Why doesn't reduce short-circuit?

Tags: swift, functional-programming

Give the following code:

```
[true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
.reduce(true, {
    print("Hello")
    return $0 && $1
})

func f(_ a: Bool) -> Bool {
    print("World")
    return a
}

f(true) && f(false) && f(true) && f(true) && f(true) && f(true) && f(true) && f(true) && f(true)
```

It prints `"Hello"` for each item in the array, but only prints `"World"` for the first two function calls, since `&&` short-circuits.

Why doesn't `reduce` follow the same behavior?
 How could this behavior be added?

**Note:** The closure gets called 15 times even after removing side-effects.

Comment: Even *if* the compiler could somehow detect that the result is determined, it would not know if  the remaining iterations need to be executed because of *wanted* side-effects. The compiler cannot read your mind!

Comment: Related: see the discussion in the comments [to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41013999/4573247) (covering the subject of a single return `reduce` closure, with no explicitly added side effects).

Comment: In your case it would simply be `let allTrue = !boolArray.contains(false)` – with short-circuiting.

Comment: @dfri `contains(where:)` from that discussion was probably the closest thing to the behavior I need. Wasn't aware of that method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because today (in 2016) it would be pretty hard to build a compiler which (in a reasonable time) analyse the code you write into the reduce closure and determine whether short circuit logic would be applicable.

You provided a simple example

```
{
    print("Hello")
    return $0 && $1
}
```

but I am sure you can imagine more complex closures where this task is not trivial.

### Another example

Look at this code

```
let text: String
let n = 1

if n > 10 {
    text = "greater than 10"
} else {
    text = "smaller than 11"
}
print(text)
```

In the last line the compiler let me print `text` because he *knows* that it will be **always** populated (whether the IF or the ELSE is executed).

Now let's look at this new snippet

```
let text: String
let n = 1

if n > 10 || n <= 10 {
    text = "greater than 10"
}

print(text)

error: constant 'text' used before being initialized
```

We know the `text` constant will always be populated.

However all the compiler knows is that when the IF condition is `false`, `text` is **not** populated.

Comment: But if the function is pure would that still be the case? Also can a compiler determine if a function is pure to begin with?

Comment: I'm curios in what way does this relate to when the compiler issues a "code will never be executed" warning. Or would that only work for something like `1 > 10` and not `n > 10` ?

Comment: Good point. I think that is detected because `1 > 10` is translated into `false` at compile time.